# Import Blob image for test in Java

Tags: java, image, unit-testing, junit, blob

Hello how can I use a Blob image for test in Java? and Import it from an URL
I need something like
Blob image = "my blob image";

Comment: Why not just mock it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a way to do it:

```
File initialFile = new File("your_file_here.png");
InputStream stream = new FileInputStream(initialFile);
byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(stream);
Blob blob = new javax.sql.rowset.serial.SerialBlob(bytes);
```

Comment: You're welcome. If this is what you were looking for, please accept my answer.